# Facing issue while loading images in Razor pages using Areas Folder structure

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

1. Areas/Project/Pages/Create.cshtml Page.

[image]

2. I have below folder structure in my project (Asp.Net Core 3.1 Razor page), I want to access images(wwwroot/images) in Areas/Project/Pages/Create.cshtml Page.

[image]

3. I am getting this error in https://localhost:44375/Project/Create page

[image]

Comment: Did you test this ? <img src="~/images/MyImage.jpg"  />

Comment: Yes I have tried it, image actually locating to https://localhost:44375/Project/images/ic_dropdown_arrow.svg but Actually images is there in wwwroot folder and working with https://localhost:44375/images/ic_dropdown_arrow.svg

Comment: Did you check for case sensitiveness of your URL and path or incorrect spelling?

Comment: Have you used `app.UseStaticFiles();`Maybe you can try to use an abosulte path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below. It's working

`<img src="/images/1.jpg" />`

[image]

[image]